# Oracle java7 config

Tags: 12.04, java, oracle

I've installed Oracle Java 7 according to [this guide](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html).
When I run `sudo update-java-alternatives -s java-7-oracle`, it gives me :

```
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for xulrunner-1.9-javaplugin.so.
update-alternatives: error: alternative /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/jexec for jexec not registered, not setting.
update-alternatives: error: alternative /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so for mozilla-javaplugin.so not registered, not setting.
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for xulrunner-1.9-javaplugin.so.
```

What is the matter?
I use ubuntu12.04 amd64.

Comment: Ignore those errors, everything will still work.

Answer (score 2):

```
Properly installing Oracle java 7 JDK and JRE on Ubuntu 64Bits and beased distributions.
```

## Properly installing Oracle java 7 JDK and JRE on Ubuntu 64Bits and beased distributions.

### OPTION 1: Step by Step

#### OPEN A TERMINAL WINDOW (uxterm or any other terminal emulator)

#### Run as root

```
sudo -i

cd /
```

#### Guarantee that command "apt-add-repository" is working (a know bug in some Ubuntu 64bits, and based distributions)

```
aptitude update

aptitude install python-software-properties
```

#### Install Oracle java PPA

```
apt-add-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
```

#### Install Oracle java

```
aptitude update

aptitude install oracle-java7-jdk oracle-java7-set-default oracle-java7-installer oracle-java7-plugin
```

#### Fix know Oracle java issues: part 1. Make the dir "/usr/lib/xulrunner-addons/plugins/"

```
mkdir -p /usr/lib/xulrunner-addons/plugins
```

#### Fix know Oracle java issues: part 2.  Register missing alternatives

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/libjavaplugin.so mozilla-javaplugin.so /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so 1

update-alternatives --set mozilla-javaplugin.so /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so

update-alternatives --install /usr/lib/xulrunner-addons/plugins/libjavaplugin.so xulrunner-1.9-javaplugin.so /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so 1

update-alternatives --set xulrunner-1.9-javaplugin.so /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so
```

#### Fix know Oracle java issues: part 3. Correct the location of the "jexec" file in "/usr/lib/jvm/.java-7-oracle.jinfo"

```
sed -i 's@jre jexec /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/jexec@jre jexec /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/jexec@g' /usr/lib/jvm/.java-7-oracle.jinfo
```

#### Update java alternatives to make Oracle java to be the default java on system

```
update-java-alternatives -s java-7-oracle
```

#### Uninstall OpenJDK java files

```
aptitude purge openjdk-7-jre openjdk-7-jre-headless openjdk-7-jre-lib default-jre default-jre-headless icedtea-7-jre-jamvm
```

#### Logout from "root" user

```
exit
```

#### Close terminal window

```
exit
```

### OPTION 2: ONE TIME SCRIPT

#### OPEN A TERMINAL WINDOW (uxterm or any other terminal emulator)

```
sudo -i

cd /

aptitude update

aptitude install python-software-properties

apt-add-repository ppa:webupd8team/java

aptitude update

aptitude install oracle-java7-jdk oracle-java7-set-default oracle-java7-installer oracle-java7-plugin

mkdir -p /usr/lib/xulrunner-addons/plugins

update-alternatives --install /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/libjavaplugin.so mozilla-javaplugin.so /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so 1

update-alternatives --set mozilla-javaplugin.so /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so

update-alternatives --install /usr/lib/xulrunner-addons/plugins/libjavaplugin.so xulrunner-1.9-javaplugin.so /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so 1

update-alternatives --set xulrunner-1.9-javaplugin.so /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so

sed -i 's@jre jexec /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/jexec@jre jexec /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/jexec@g' /usr/lib/jvm/.java-7-oracle.jinfo

update-java-alternatives -s java-7-oracle

aptitude purge openjdk-7-jre openjdk-7-jre-headless openjdk-7-jre-lib default-jre default-jre-headless icedtea-7-jre-jamvm

exit

exit
```